# Good reference texts for introduction to partial differential equation?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, partial-differential-equations

As the title, are there any good reference texts for introduction to partial differential equation?

Comment: Did you try [Evans](http://books.google.com/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC)?

Comment: Consider also Salsa's book: http://www.amazon.com/Partial-Differential-Equations-Action-Universitext/dp/8847007518

Comment: A related question: [Good 1st PDE book for self study](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/good-1st-pde-book-for-self-study).

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your question depends on whether you're more interested in the theory of partial differential equations or in how to compute the solutions to concrete equations.

At a more theoretical level you can try Ronald Evans' Partial Differential Equations: Second Edition (Graduate Studies in Mathematics). This is one of the most complete textbooks on PDEs around, I think.

On the more practical side, you can try Polyanin's Handbook of Partial Differential Equations. This is more of a solution recipe book, but has interesting tips and ideas on how to tackle a large number of problems.

Comment: I think you mean Lawrence C. Evans in your second paragraph.

Comment: oops, sorry, honest mistake!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend "Partial Differential Equations with Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems" written by Asmar. It is a text for beginners in the subject, but eventually it gets very far, to a thorough treatment of Green's functions. It does also include a lot of material on Bessels functions.