# Textbook for Partial Differential Equations with a viewpoint towards Geometry.

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

Though similar questions have been asked at [Good 1st PDE book for self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/good-1st-pde-book-for-self-study)
and [Good reference texts for introduction to partial differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194152/good-reference-texts-for-introduction-to-partial-differential-equation?lq=1) but none of them really answer my query, so I am bounded to ask this.

I am basically interested in Differential and Riemannian Geometry and one of my Professors told me that it will be a good idea if I acquire a sound knowledge of PDE. I know about the basics of PDE (i.e., methods of solving PDE ) but I don't have any firm knowledge of the analysis which goes on in there.

So, my question is that what will be a good textbook to start learning PDE that could help in undrstanding the $\it{analysis}$ portion as well as with applications of PDE in Differential/Riemannian Geometry.

Background : I have studied Measure Theory, Functional Analysis, Complex Analysis and some Fourier Analysis (from Stein & Shakarchi's book on Fourier Analysis). I am currently studying Algebraic Topology, Differential and Riemannian Geometry (from Do Carmo's book).

Thanks!!

Comment: It doesn't quite fit the bill, but I really liked [Arnold's book](http://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Partial-Differential-Equations-Universitext/dp/3540404481/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1411846262&sr=8-2&keywords=arnold+partial+differential).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard PDE textbooks would serve you well as a start. For example Fritz John's *Partial Differential Equations* and LC Evans' *Partial Differential Equations* are both very good for just the analysis aspects.

In parallel you can consult Michael Taylor's 3 volume set titled, again, *Partial Differential Equations*. Taylor's books develops similar breadth and slightly more depth as Evans' book, but also with an eye toward geometry.

Once you get a few things under your belt, J Jost's *Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis* is a classic in the field.

For more advanced topics, particular related to geometry, two very good books have been written by Thierry Aubin: *Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds, Monge-Ampere Equations* and *Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry*.

---

If you particularly want to study elliptic type problems, you can also consider going from John's book to Fang-Hua Lin's *Elliptic partial differential equations* then to Gilbarg & Trudinger on the one hand, and Caffarelli & Cabré on the other for the analysis.

Comment: thanks ... i was thinking to start with Evans' book