# Good partial differential equation books.

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I have good command in real and complex analysis as well i had studied ordinary differential equation. Now i am trying to study partial differential equation but facing a lot of problems. Please suggest me some books which are suitable for me. I start with Strauss book but it is not comfortable for me. Also tell me books in which Cauchy problem for PDE is given in very simple and nice form. I studied ODE from tenenbaum dover book which is very nice to digest. I want same type of books for PDE. Please suggest me . Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might be interested by the discussions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2827).

Comment: Thanks................

Answer (score 5):

The book in PDE's people usually start with is **Partial Differential Equations**, by **Lawrence C. Evans**. You can find it [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Partial-Differential-Equations-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics-Lawrence/0821849743), for example.

This book covers the essentials you should start with when facing a first approach to PDE's. This is obviously subject to personal opinion. In particular you can find chapters on *Representation formulas* for both linear and non-linear equations, theory on *Sobolev and Holder spaces*, *Elliptic equations*, *Calculus of Variations* and much more. It is really a very complete book in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Lectures on partial differential equations by VI Arnold is a very well written book with nice geometric insight.

Answer (score 1):

Regards @neelkanth . You could try *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations : A Computational Approach* by Aslak Tveito and Ragnar Winther. It starts with Cauchy problem, method of characteristic, and it is quite soft. Besides proof, it also shows numerical simulation result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a bit of physics to keep the rigor interesting, I'd recommend Guenther and Lee's Partial Differential Equations of Mathematical Physics and Integral Equations. I used it in grad school, suited me fine. Looks like Dover publishes it now.

Answer (score -1):

You can try M.D.Raisinghania ordinary and partial differential equation book. A solved chapter on Cauchy problem is there in this book.

Comment: Its very rough book.....