# Easy to read partial differential equations book?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I'm looking for an easy to read undergraduate book on partial differential equations, ideally something that is not much harder than a multivariable calculus/ordinary differential equations book.

I am preparing for a course which is using the text by Walter Strauss, but I found this text a bit difficult to read. Specifically, I found that many of the derivations were missing steps that were not obvious to me or provided little justification for the manipulations. When I searched for introductory books however the Strauss book seems to be recommended.

Google seems to recommend, among others:

- Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers by Farlow
- Introduction to Partial Differential Equations by Peter Olver

I have ruled out:

- Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction by Walter Strauss
- An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations by Michael Renardy
- Partial Differential Equations by Fritz John
- Partial Differential Equations by Lawrence C Evans

My background is having read A First Course in Differential Equations with Modelling Applications by Dennis Zill. Would I be better off reading the extended version of this book (Differential Equations with Boundary Value Problems)? I was a little bit hesitant because I was not sure how relevant the book is to PDEs. The chapters I have not read are Fourier Series, Boundary Value Problems in Rectangular Coordinates, Boundary Value Problems in Other Coordinate Systems, Integral Transforms and Numerical Solutions of Partial Differential Equations.

EDIT: I ended up finishing about half the book, which is everything covered in my course, Chapters 1 through 7.

Comment: The book by L C Evans was used as a textbook when I took PDE

Comment: I think you would benefit greatly by reading the chapters in the extended version of Zill.  You would get a nice overview of the subject, and everything you learned would be relevant to the course you're going to take.  I've never looked at Zill, but I'm sure it's fine.

Comment: I think B. Goddard is right, but also perhaps you should be given some encouragement to stick with Strauss. A book that leaves some steps out trains you to figure those steps out yourself. And it is guaranteed to help with your future class. I'll also mention that there's a solution manual if you look hard enough...

Comment: It's Fritz John, not John Fritz. That's a good book, but it's more advanced than Strauss. Generally speaking, you can rule out any book mentioned here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72318/textbooks-for-pde-between-strauss-and-folland. But you might get some useful suggestions here instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/good-1st-pde-book-for-self-study.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I am quite fond of **Evan's Partial differential equations** as an introductory textbook.

I would not expect to find something really "easy to read", though, simply because the subject matter tends not be all that easy.

Comment: Evans is a great book but if OP is having trouble with the Strauss book (Ch 1: "Where PDEs come from", Ch 2: 1D Wave eq, Ch 3: Heat equation on $(0,\infty)$, Ch 4: Introduction of separation of variables...Ch 10: generalisation to 2D) then there's going to be blood sweat and tears on reading Evans

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the advice to continue with the Zill book, and to fill in steps in math books such as Strauss, but if you want something really easy, I have some lecture notes on differential equations at http://bterrell.net
that introduce various topics in ODE and PDE by focusing on some applications.

Answer (score 0):

For undergraduate level, the book "Partial Differential Equations An Introduction" by Walter A. Strauss is decent and is highly recommended

Comment: The OP wrote: "I am preparing for a course which is using the text by Walter Strauss, but I found this text a bit difficult to read" so I think suggesting Strauss might not be the most useful answer. Maybe it will be useful for others, though.